# Getting first array element within object using destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
x = { foo: [ { foo: 'foo' } ], bar: [ { bar: 'bar' } ] };
```

Is it possible to get `{foo: 'foo'}` and `{ bar: 'bar' }`  in one line?

Something like this

```
({ foo, bar } = x);
```

would produce `[{"foo":"foo"}] [{"bar":"bar"}]` which are two arrays and not objects. Of course these arrays can be further destructured, but I'm interested in a one line implementation

Comment: `const { foo: [foo], bar: [bar] } = x`

Answer (score 0):

You can use array destruction to get the first element:

```
const { foo: [ firstFoo ], bar: [firstBar ]} = x;
```